# Use Doctrine in symfony front controller

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Is it possible to use a custom doctrine entity manager in the front controller?

```
orm:
    default_entity_manager: default
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: client_connection
            mappings:
               AppBundle: ~
        master:
            connection: master_connection
            mappings:
                Master:
                    type: annotation
                    dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../src/Clients/TestBundle/Entity
                    is_bundle: false
                    alias: Master
                    prefix: Clients\TestBundle\Entity
```

In a service I can use my custom entity manager like this

```
$result = $this->entityManagerMaster->getRepository("Master:Client")->findOneBy(array("domain" => $host));
```

But how can I use this entityManager with my custom connection in the app.php front controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to then you can do this in app.php:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();

$kernel->boot();
$em = $kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');
```

However, as @xabbuh pointed out, you probably don't really want to do this.  Kernel listeners (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-request) are almost certainly the way to go.

Comment: Thank you! I really need this because I have for every tenant an own environment (because of cache, database and so on). All tenants are saved in a database and therefor i need doctrine.